# Upload speeds drastically different between two computers

Tags: internet, ethernet

This problem is very simple. My pc, with a Realtek PCLe 2.5GbE Family Controller network adapter gets an upload speed of 200mbps, while my 2020 macbook pro gets an upload speed of up to 700mbps. They are connected to the exact same ethernet cord for their tests. Any ideas for what could be causing this massive difference?
Quick little note. I have Mcafee virus scanner run everyday and have never encountered a malware/virus alert, so that could not be an issue.

Edit: here is a picture of my network adapter properties (ip info scribbled out obviously)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwmcv.jpg)

Edit #2: an interesting thing I have found is that when I start the test on both computers, the upload shoots up fast to ~300mbs (in like 2 seconds). At almost the same time, my PC will slowly decrease and my macbook will slowly increase. Its as if it reaches 300mbps then chooses to go down to a certain point (pc) or go up to a certain point (macbook)

EDIT #3: I just ran a speed test through my router's online settings, and got 800 upload and download. Not sure if this download speed uses any or my pc's resources or is directly ran through the router only.

Comment: @John would this be necessary? My realtek card is capable of 1000mbps up and down, or atleast says so in network settings. Of course, the whole issue could just be a faulty card, but I'm going to just rule that out as it is not as probable as something else causing my issue. I appreciate the suggestion though :D

Comment: @Ramhound Just updated the post. I hope I pulled the right adapter properties, if not where would I find them?

Comment: @Ramhound try changing what?

Comment: We might have something here. So within the Card's controller properties, under speed & duplex, it was set to 1gbps. I changed it to 2.5 GBPS full duplexed, restarted my computer, and now my upload has gone down to 130 mbps (could just be a fluxuation and the change didnt hurt it). also, in the same settings I screenshotted, nothing changed either. I am using a cat 6 cord.

Comment: @Ramhound Also another side note, when I run the speedtest I have noticed that when the upload test starts, it instantly jumps up to around 300, but within 2 seconds of it starting it slowly falls down to ~150mbps. not sure if this is important or not, figured I'd add just incase

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure about the router and not sure where to check for that. The adapter does not have an auto disable gigabit option.I'm trying out that realtek driver right now

Comment: @Ramhound by the way thank you so much for the help, even if we cant find a fix i have been searching for a while now and youve gone out of your way to brainstorm and troubleshoot for a while now and I appreciate that a lot

Comment: @Ramhound Downloading and restarting my pc after installing didn't fix it, although it did jump to 360 off the start, still dropped to 170 by the end. It installed correctly too, I see the new version as in the driver details now.

Comment: @Ramhound Just looked for a second ethernet port and noticed the ethernet port on my PC says 2.5gb, if thats what you were asking

Answer (score -2):

"My pc, with a Realtek PCLe 2.5GbE Family Controller network adapter" - That will be your problem.  Realtek make really bad network cards.